# Dina's Paintings

Tags: code-golf

Dina loves most numbers. In fact, she loves every number that is not a multiple of n (she really hates the number n). For her friends’ birthdays this year, Dina has decided to draw each of them a sequence of n−1 flowers. Each of the flowers will contain between 1 and n−1 flower petals (inclusive). Because of her hatred of multiples of n, the total number of petals in any non-empty contiguous subsequence of flowers cannot be a multiple of n. For example, if n=5, then the top two paintings are valid, while the bottom painting is not valid since the second, third and fourth flowers have a total of 10 petals. (The top two images are Sample Input 3 and 4.)[image]

Dina wants her paintings to be unique, so no two paintings will have the same sequence of flowers. To keep track of this, Dina recorded each painting as a sequence of n−1 numbers specifying the number of petals in each flower from left to right. She has written down all valid sequences of length n−1 in lexicographical order. A sequence a<sub>1</sub>,a<sub>2</sub>,…,a<sub>(n−1)</sub> is lexicographically smaller than b<sub>1</sub>,b<sub>2</sub>,…,b<sub>n−1</sub> if there exists an index k such that a<sub>i</sub>=b<sub>i</sub> for i < k and a<sub>k</sub> < b<sub>k</sub>.

***What is the kth sequence on Dina’s list?***

**Input**
The input consists of a single line containing two integers n (2≤n≤1000), which is Dina’s hated number, and k (1≤k≤10<sup>18</sup>), which is the index of the valid sequence in question if all valid sequences were ordered lexicographically. It is guaranteed that there exist at least k valid sequences for this value of n.

***Output***
Display the *k*th sequence on Dina’s list.

```
Sample Input 1
4 3    
Sample Output 1
2 1 2
```

---

```
Sample Input 2
2 1    
Sample Output 2
1
```

---

```
Sample Input 3
5 22   
Sample Output 3
4 3 4 2
```

---

```
Sample Input 4
5 16  
Sample Output 4
3 3 3 3
```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG. Nice first question.

Comment: Did you write this question or is it from another source?

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 87 bytes

```
n#k=[d|d<-mapM id$[1..n]<$[2..n],all(\x->mod x n>0)$p d]!!k
p(x:y)=scanl(+)x<>p$y
p x=x
```

Uses 0-based indexing. Needs the latest version of `Prelude` which is not installed on TIO, hence an additional `import`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vce7DoIwFADQna@4pB0gCoFGFkOZXJ0ckeHGEm3o4wYwKYn/XuOG08l54TKNxkRtyc8rXHDF8jZa/Zz9m6Jjk@zVR7WFRbqCVryvy9INLe/FzyMak91D0VmvIIDrqpwTqCFNp4SycN5yuTzQmeyQh7YjviUEQYZoUTuQoHwCQLN2K3A4MbGbYNVuDRP1X@smfgE)

```
   d|d<-mapM id$[1..n]<$[2..n]    -- keep all 'd' from the lists of numbers [1..n] of
                                  -- length n-1
     , all(\x->      )            -- where all elements 'x' from
                       p d        -- the sums of the subsequences of 'd'
               mod x n>0          -- are not a multiple of n
 [                           ]!!k -- pick the 'k'th element

p(x:y)=scanl(+)x<>p$y             -- the sums of subsequences are calculated by
                                  -- prepending the cumulative sums of the list to
                                  -- a recursive call with the tail of the list
p x=x                             -- base case for recursion: empty list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 12 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
’ṗ`Ẇ§%ẠʋƇ⁸ị@
```

A dyadic Link accepting `n` on the left and `k` on the right.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASkA1v9qZWxsef//4oCZ4bmXYOG6hsKnJeG6oMqLxofigbjhu4tA////Nf8yMg)** (no way this will work for large n, but would in theory)

#### How?

```
’ṗ`Ẇ§%ẠʋƇ⁸ị@ - Link: integer n, integer k
’            - decrement n -> n-1
  `          - use for both arguments of:
 ṗ           -   Cartesian power (all (n-1)^2 flower sequences - lex order)
         ⁸   - chain's left argument, n (as right argument for...)
        Ƈ    - filter keep those (sequences) which are truthy under:
       ʋ     -   last four links as a dyad (f(sequence, n)):
   Ẇ         -     all ((n-1)n/2) contiguous sublists (of the sequence)
    §        -     sum each
     %       -     modulo (n)
      Ạ      -     all? (all non-zero?)
           @ - with swapped arguments (i.e. f(k, listOfValidSequences)
          ị  -   index into (1-based)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), <s>74</s> 68 bytes

```perl6
{([X] (1..^$^a)xx$a-1).grep(!*[^*X.. ^*].grep:{$_&.sum%%$a})[$^b-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1ojOiJWQcNQTy9OJS5Rs6JCJVHXUFMvvSi1QENRKzpOK0JPTyFOKxYsYlWtEq@mV1yaq6qqklirGa0Sl6RrGFv7vzixUiFNw0THWNOaC8I20jGEs011jIyQOIZmmtb/AQ)

Anonymous code block that returns a list of numbers, or an integer in the case of \$n=2\$.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{([X] (1..^$^a)xx$a-1).grep(!*[^*X.. ^*].grep:{$_&.sum%%$a})[$^b-1]}
{                                                                  }  # Anonymous code block
 ([X] (1..^$^a)xx$a-1)  # From all n length sequences of 1 to n-1
                      .grep(                               )   # Filter by
                            !           .grep:{          }  # None of
                             *[^*X.. ^*]    # All partitions (including empty lists)
                                               $_    # Are non-empty
                                                 &.sum%%$a  # And the sum is divisible by n
                                                            [$^b-1]  # Get the kth index of the list
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 35 bytes

```
ＮθＩ↨§Φ…Ｘθ⁻θ²Ｘθ⊖θ¬ΦθΦλ¬﹪Σ✂↨ιθνλ¹θ⊖ηθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY05DsIwEEX7nMLlWDIFS5eKRUgpEkXkBMYZEUteiGMDtzc2IYju6/83b8TAnbBcxViZe/BN0Fd0MNKyaJ00Ho588nDgE8LeV6bHF5yl8gm5cHNDaO0z44zU0oQphw2ljPzqEwqHGo3HPknz1Fi/KNL@TWrua9sHZaELGjolBc6PJSNjOjSMJGydHdlEP7Z//7BMZYy7YhtXD/UG) Link is to verbose version of code. Works by taking the range \$ n^{n-2} \ldots n^{n-1}-1 \$ in base \$ n \$ and filtering out illegal sequences (including ones with zero digits). Explanation:

```
Ｎ                                   Input `n` as a number
 θ                                  Save in variable
        θ                           `n`
       Ｘ                            To the power
          θ                         `n`
         ⁻                          Minus
           ²                        2
      …                             Ranged up to
             θ                      `n`
            Ｘ                       To the power
               θ                    `n`
              ⊖                     Decremented
     Φ                              Filtered `i` by
                ¬                   Not
                  θ                 Implicit range `0` .. `n-1`
                 Φ                  Filtered `l` by
                    λ               Implicit range `0` .. `l`
                   Φ                Filtered `m` by
                     ¬              Not
                       Σ            Sum
                          ι         `i`
                         ↨          Converted to base
                           θ        `q`
                        ✂           Sliced
                            ν       From `m`
                             λ      To `l`
                              ¹     Step 1
                      ﹪             Modulo
                               θ    `n`
    §                               Indexed by
                                 η  Second input `k`
                                ⊖   Decremented
   ↨                                Converted to base
                                  θ `n`
  Ｉ                                 Cast to string
                                    Implicitly printed
```